# writing slower than the operation itself?

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2012, stack

I am struggling to understand behavior of my functions. 
My code is written in C++ in visual studio 2012. Running on Windows 7 64 bit. I am working with 2D arrays of float numbers. when I time my function I see that the time for function is reduced by 10X or more if I just stop writing my results to the output pointer. Does that mean that writing is slow?
Here is an example:

```
void TestSpeed(float** pInput, float** pOutput)
{    
    UINT32 y, x, i, j;
    for (y = 3; y < 100-3; y++)
    {       
        for (x = 3; x < 100-3; x++)
        {
            float fSum = 0;
            for (i = y - 3; i <= y+3; i++)
            {               
                for (j = x-3; j <= x+3; j++)
                {
                    fSum += pInput[y][x]*exp(-(pInput[y][x]-pInput[i][j])*(pInput[y][x]-pInput[i][j]));
                }
            }
            pOutput[y][x] = fSum;
        }
    }

}
```

If I comment out the line "pOutput[y][x] = fSum;" then the functions runs very quick. Why is that?
I am calling 2-3 such functions sequentially. Would it help to use stack instead of heap to write chunk of results and passing it onto next function and then write back to heap buffer after that chunk is ready?
In some cases I saw that if I replace pOutput[y][x] by a line buffer allocated on stack like,
float fResult[100] and use it to store results works faster for larger data size.

Comment: The compiler, on seeing a bunch of calculations whose result is discarded, simply doesn't do those calculations.

Comment: It would help if you told which programming language this is.

Comment: @Juhana C++. I also updated my question with more info. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Yes, it is faster.  The optimizer will completely remove the function since it has no side-effects.  It is infinitely faster, not just x10 :)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes a lot of operation and it needs time. Depending on what you are doing with the output you may consider the diagonalization or decomposition of your input matrix. Or you can look for values in yor output which are n times an other value etc and don't calculate the exponential for theese.